# Calling on a method with parameters a specific number of times

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm using an example Turtle project from BlueJ to trace out polygons. I already have a method that would sketch a polygon after providing it with the number of sides and length of the sides. Now, I would like to call upon that method a specific number of times such that I can specify, for example, that I would like to create 3 polygons, then provide the above parameters for each polygon, then have it proceed to sketch it out.

My method for sketching out a polygon is as follows:

```
public void drawPolygon(int numberOfSides, int lengthOfSide, Color penColor){
    world.dropIn(fred);
    fred.setColor(penColor);
    fred.penUp();
    fred.left(90);
    fred.forward(200);
    fred.right(90);
    fred.penDown();
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfSides; i++) {
        fred.right( 360 / numberOfSides );
        fred.forward(lengthOfSide);
    }
    world.removeTurtle(fred);
```

FYI: `fred` is the name of my turtle and the `Color` related lines are for changing the color of the pen fred is using.

I've tried writing the following:

```
public void drawPolygons(int numberOfPolygons){
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfPolygons; i++){
        drawPolygon(int numberOfSides, int lengthOfSide, Color penColor);
    }
}
```

But I get a variety of errors. Is it possible to call a method with parameters within another method with parameters or am I barking mad?

I'm sorry if this is too basic a question for Stackoverflow, I'm completely new to programming and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: of course it is, or we would never have applications with more than one functionality or apps that has anything other than one block of code! you are using data types in the invocation which is not right, just call the method directly with the values. Data types are specified when writing the method not calling it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to call a method with parameters within another method with parameters...

Yes, this is a common paradigm.  You just need to fix your invocation of drawPolygon:

```
public void drawPolygons(int numberOfPolygons){
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfPolygons; i++){
        drawPolygon(numberOfSides, lengthOfSide, penColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: `numberOfSides`, `lengthOfSide`, and `penColor` are external parameters that I input when I create the polygon. When I try to remove the type declarations, BlueJ throws up the error that those variables cannot be found

Comment: try calling drawPolygon(int, int, Color) from a place where those parameters are accessible.